# when writting a XPATH i could able to access inside #doucment..inside a #document i have to input inside a html/body my ntml page below

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath, iframe

[this is my html page please help on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWhDu.png)

and my xpath below : `(//span[text()='Information']//following::div[contains(@class,'edit-area')])[1]/iframe`

bt when am running mr script its shwing no iframe present in  a partiulay window.Even i tryed to search a frame by using a 
WHEN i try to get a size of frame showing that iframe size is =0

Comment: What is your exact _Manual Step_ which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: actualy i want to input in side a #document HTML/BODY finally i did it thank you so much for the response DebanjanB

Comment: one more issue in my organization automaitacaly system wil get lock . once a PC get lock or else if leave a browser and switch to someother window all my test scripts getting fail but in a background Eclipse IDE stil writting my scripts . please any suggestion on this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ID` instead of `xpath`

```
WebElement iFrameLoc = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-tinymce-0_ifr"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrameLoc));
//do your operations 
//---------
//Switch to default frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Tahnk you @iamsankalp,Actualy i want to input inside html/body i couldnt able to input even i have one more Id inside body i have id also.

Comment: tq so much for the response finally i done it thank you so much @iamsankalp89

Comment: but one more issue i my organization automaitacaly system wil get lock . once a PC get lock or else if leave a browser and switch to someother window all my test scripts getting fail but in a background Eclipse IDE stil writting my scripts . please any suggestion on this..

Comment: I will let u know, I need to some R&D on this

Comment: k thank you ill be waiting for your response..

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement frame =driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Information']//following::div[contains(@class,'edit-area')])[1]/iframe"));
          System.out.println(frame);
         driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
         WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/p"));
          System.out.println(elem);


         Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
         actions.moveToElement(elem);
         actions.click();
         actions.sendKeys("SOME DATA");
         actions.build().perform();

         System.out.println("finished");
```

Comment: finally this is worked for me